# Tailwind cursor single direction not working properly on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, tailwind-css

In the tailwind sandbox below, the cursor should be a single direction like pointing east for example but it doesn't work for me on Chrome or Firefox. Are there browser compatibility issues or am I doing something incorrectly? How can I make it show only one direction?

https://play.tailwindcss.com/pRoZhgulNp

```html
<div class="flex h-screen w-full flex-col items-center justify-center gap-6 bg-slate-50">
  <div class="h-10 w-60 cursor-e-resize bg-red-300">East: should be -></div>
  <div class="h-10 w-60 cursor-ew-resize bg-green-300">East-West: should be <-></div>
  <div class="h-10 w-60 cursor-s-resize bg-red-300">South</div>
  <div class="h-10 w-60 cursor-ns-resize bg-green-300">North-South</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me on macOS, both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @zcorpan Thanks. I'm on windows, I wonder if it's a windows vs mac thing. Will see if anyone else with windows can confirm it not working. Otherwise, I'll have to see what's unique to my setup